# How to pull movie id(tmdb api) , @PathVarible

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I started my first spring boot project. That's why it's not enough.
Already looked for Stack Overflows and Googling.

I'd appreciate your help.

**tmdb API query for details **

```
'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/343611?api_key=87bad1aa...~'

movie_id : 343611
```

**Controller**

```
import com.example.joyit.service.MovieSearchService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("moviesearch")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MovieSearchController {

private final MovieSearchService movieSearchService;
    /*
     * localhost:8080/moviesearch/detail
     *
     * @param movieid
     * @return ResponseEntity
     */

    @GetMapping("/detail/{movieid}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> searchDetail(@PathVariable int movieid) {
        log.info("[Request] search detail");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(movieSearchService.MovieSearchDetailApi(movieid), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@Service
public class MovieSearchService {
    @Value("${tmdb.api}")
    private String tmdbkey;
    private String movieDetailUrl="https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie";


    public MovieSearchDetailDto MovieSearchDetailApi(int movieid) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.set("Authorization", "TMDB_API_KEY" + tmdbkey); //Authorization 설정
        HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders); 
        URI targetUrl = UriComponentsBuilder
                .fromUriString(movieDetailUrl) 
                .port(movieid)
                .queryParam("api_key", tmdbkey)
                .queryParam("language", "ko-KR")
                .build()
                .encode(StandardCharsets.UTF_8) 
                .toUri();


        ResponseEntity<MovieSearchDetailDto> result = restTemplate.exchange(targetUrl, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, MovieSearchDetailDto.class);
        return result.getBody(); 
    }
}
```

**MovieSearchDetailDto**

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class MovieSearchDetailDto {
    List<Results> results = new ArrayList<>();

    static class Results{
        public String title;
        public int moive_id;
        public String poster_path;
        public String release_date;
        public String overview;
    }
}
```

Using `@PathVariable` in Controller copied the code through Googling. But I don't know how to make Uri in Service to utilize `movie_id`. `Movie_id` used `port()` because it is int type, but it doesn't run on postman.

[image]

**Expectation**

```
{
   "id": 76600,
  "poster_path": "/t6HIqrRAclMCA60NsSmeqe9RmNV.jpg",
  "release_date": "2022-12-14",
  "title": "Avatar: The Way of Water",
   "overview": "Set more than a decade after the events of the first film, learn the story of the Sully family (Jake, Neytiri, and their kids), the trouble that follows them, the lengths they go to keep each other safe, the battles they fight to stay alive, and the tragedies they endure.",
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your current one implementation i think you should construct the `URI` something like this:

```
URL targetUrl = UriComponentsBuilder
    .fromUriString(movieDetailUrl + "/" + movieid)
    .queryParam("api_key", tmdbkey)
    .queryParam("language", "ko-KR")
    .build()
    .encode(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    .toUri();
```

You dont need to pass `movieid` as a URI `port`.

Also `Results` class:

```
 static class Results{
        public String title;
        public int id; //instead of moive_id
        public String poster_path;
        public String release_date;
        public String overview;
    }
```

Can you try this one builder ? and give me feedback if it is ok so.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
But it comes out as empty in postman.
I'm not sure what's wrong.

-postman-
http://localhost:8080/moviesearch/detail/76600
`{
    "results": []
}`

Comment: in your case you have to get result by `id` can you change `restTemplate.exchange(targetUrl, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, MovieSearchDetailDto.class); ` to `restTemplate.exchange(targetUrl, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, Results.class);`, will be any changes ?

Comment: by the way this is another problem `why you are getting result as empty one`, main problem of the question was solved and also i think you should inspect and solve it in your own.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your comment was also a hint at the empty price.Thanks to you, I solved it. The additional question was given because you asked for feedback. I didn't mean to burden you. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: you are always welcome.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that the issue is with constructing the URL

check out this code snippet

```
URI targetUrl = UriComponentsBuilder
                    .fromUriString(movieDetailUrl) 
                    .path("/{movieid}")
                    .queryParam("api_key", tmdbkey)
                    .queryParam("language", "ko-KR")
                    .buildAndExpand(movieid)
                    .encode(StandardCharsets.UTF_8) 
                    .toUri();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But it comes out as empty in postman. I'm not sure what's wrong. -postman- localhost:8080/moviesearch/detail/76600 `{     "results": [] }`